# Question/Matter of definition?

Tags: phrases, expressions, translation

A "Definitionsfråga", as it is called in Swedish, is for instance if you talk about what's good and bad, you can remark that it depends on what you mean by good and bad. You could might as well remark that it is a "definitionsfråga". What is that called in English?

Comment: In Swedish, _fråga_ is 'question', and that can work in English, but saying _It's a question of definition_ means that finding or constructing the correct definition will solve the problem, even if it isn't a definitional problem. On the other hand, _matter_ is far more vague and _It's a matter of definition_ is often used to mean "You define it as `X` and I define it as `Y` and we aren't going to agree."

Comment: In complex areas, it is sensible to start off by 'defining terms'.

Comment: I think that *Well, that all depends on what you mean by X and Y" is almost a fixed phrase in English for this.

Comment: Araicaria: I want to use something shorter than that phrase.

This is basically what I've written: Throughout the history, there have always been great leaders and there will probably come many more in the future; some with good intentions and some with bad. That however, is a matter of definition.

Comment: In regard to your history example, I would say it's more a matter of "opinion".  But if it really is a situation where one person has a different idea of what a word means, you could say it's a matter of "semantics".

Answer (score 1):

The most idiomatic way to express this in English is probably to say "**It's all a question of / it comes down to** how you define 'good' and 'bad' in this context".

Answer (score -1):

I think **It's [all] a matter of opinion** is probably the most idiomatic phrase for this in English.

But then that's just my opinion.

Comment: Seems like this is about something being a matter of terminology/definition, not of opinion. But then, maybe it all depends on what you mean by "*opinion*". ;-)